# checking if element's text is same as another element's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do is when I click on a text, if another div has a child that contains this text fade in. but it's not working

```js
$('.rel-head').click(function() {

  if ($('.art-h .head-art'): contains($(this).text())) {
    $(this).parent().fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">some text</div>
</div>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">anoter text</div>
</div>
<div class "related-heads">
  <h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Need the html as well. Also you have :contains not .contains

Comment: for :contains use `$('.art-h .head-art:contains($(this).text()'))`

Comment: `if($('.art-h .head-art').text() == $(this).text()) { ... }`

Comment: <div class="art-h">
   <div class="head-art">some text</div>
</div>
<h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1>
@basic

Comment: @mark.hch but how to select this one $('.art-h .head-art') if there is more than one have the same class?

Comment: add the html mark up in the OP as well

Comment: @IbrahimYousry It will return an array which you can directly access elements with like `$('.art-h .head-art')[0]` or `$('.art-h .head-art')[1]` etc.

Comment: <div class="art-h"> <div class="head-art">some text</div> </div>
<div class="art-h"> <div class="head-art">anoter text</div> </div> <h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1> 
@guradio

Comment: but if I don't know which one is this element how I can use this method
@KenoClayton

Comment: given HTML does not show clicked element parent

Comment: <div class="art-h"> <div class="head-art">some text</div> </div> <div class="art-h"> <div class="head-art">anoter text</div> </div>
<div class"related-heads">
 <h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1>
</div>
@guradio

Comment: not sure if this is what you actually want but https://jsfiddle.net/5vyrj71x/ it's not dynamic but hopefully if this is what you are looking for, this can give you some idea

Comment: It sounds like you don't need an `if` check then, just select any element with that text and change it `$('.art-h .head-art:contains("' + $(this).text() + '")').parent().fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();` https://jsfiddle.net/hf137ykb

Answer (score 1):

1. Use selector `:contains` and concat the string properly.

```js
$('.rel-head').click(function() {

  if ($('.art-h .head-art:contains('+$(this).text()+')')) {
    $(this).parent().fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">some text</div>
</div>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">anoter text</div>
</div>
<div class "related-heads">
  <h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very efficient to search the entire body every time you click on each of the specified items.

This is what I'd do.

```js
let headArtArray = $('.art-h .head-art'); //Assign it to a variable early to reduce searching

$('.rel-head').click(function() {
  let el = $(this);
  let text = el.text();

  for (let i = 0; i < headArtArray.length; i++) {
    
    if (headArtArray[i].innerText.includes(text)) {
      el.parent().fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(headArtArray[i]).fadeOut();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">some text</div>
</div>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">anoter text</div>
</div>
<div class "related-heads">
  <h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not working and the console is giving me an error in this line 
if (headArtArray[i].text().includes(text)) {

Comment: @IbrahimYousry I'll fix that

Comment: @IbrahimYousry Fixed, just changed `text()` to `innerText`.

Comment: if($('.art-h .head-art').text() == $(this).text()) { ... } 

if it like this will it work, and if it will how can I select this specific $('.art-h .head-art')

Comment: The code snippet posted above does work as expected. Double check what you have to ensure it is consistent.

Comment: You can select a specific one by filtering through the array like I did.

Comment: but in your code both are fading out, I want only the one which not contains the text fades out

Comment: @IbrahimYousry Oh I did not understand that's what you wanted to do. I'll modify the code again