# select element in if condition if there are more sibling elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select this element $('.art-h .head-art') that has the same text if there are more sibling elements with the same class

```
if($('.art-h .head-art').text() == $(this).text()) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you post sample HTML, that will help.

Comment: <div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">some text</div>
</div>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">anoter text</div>
</div>
<div class "related-heads">
  <h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1>
</div>
@Bibberty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checking if element's text is same as another element's text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544614/checking-if-elements-text-is-same-as-another-elements-text)

Comment: this is a duplicate OP

Comment: @guradio I think he is actually trying to select the element that contains the text he is looking for. Not where an element is equal to another. i.e. think `this` is likely a search.

Comment: is it basically the same questoin @Bibberty

Comment: That fair. Also on reflection it looks like the ask is for a scoped sibling search.

Comment: What do you want to do ya @IbrahimYousry exactly??

Comment: Also.. *same text* of what? of `.rel-head`? .And in which event you need to run this `if` statement `onload`? on `<h1> click`?

Comment: there are a lot of related headings or articles all has the class .rel-head, I want when I click on any one the article's head which is has the class .head-art fadeIn and the other articles fadeOut. or if there is another way to do that. @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @guradio the comment above

Comment: @Bibberty the comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll need to use `.filter` .. Try the next code

```js
$('.rel-head').click(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  $('.art-h .head-art').filter(function(){
      return $(this).text().trim() == el.text().trim();
  }).toggle();  // change toggle() with any action you want
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">some text</div>
</div>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">another text</div>
</div>
<div class="related-heads">
  <h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1>
</div>
<div class="related-heads">
  <h1 class="rel-head">another text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You're totally Welcome @IbrahimYousry .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using vanilla JS and the `find()` method.

Does this work for you?

```js
const getArt = (text) => {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.head-art')).find(e => e.innerText === text);
};

console.log(getArt('some text'));

console.log(getArt('anoter text'));
```

```html
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">some text</div>
</div>
<div class="art-h">
  <div class="head-art">anoter text</div>
</div>
<div class "related-heads">
  <h1 class="rel-head">some text</h1>
</div>
```